# How can I have R skip over one segment embedded in a wider line of code?

Tags: r, syntax, tidyverse, magrittr

How can I have R skip over one segment embedded in a wider line of code?
In the code below, I would like for R to compute the operations for var1 and var3.

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(newvar= df$var1 + df$var2 + df$var3)
```

To note: I get I could use # to have R ignore all the line, but I just want it to ignore `+ df$var2`

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the line differently and commenting works:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(newvar= 
           df$var1 
         + df$var2 
         + df$var3
        )
```

Now you can comment out any of the parts, e.g.

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(newvar= 
           df$var1 
#        + df$var2 
         + df$var3
        )
```

Normally it's a bad idea to put operators at the start of a line instead of the end because R might think the previous line ends the whole statement, but in this the parens around the whole thing mean that's not an issue.